# Volume 2 of Proceeding ICM 1966

Tags: reference-request, soft-question

As can seen in the webpage on international union of mathematics [ICM](https://www.mathunion.org/icm/proceedings), the proceedings of the congress in 1966 published in three volumes. But there exist only volume I and III; and not volume II.

The question arises because I wanted to find a paper by Alberto Calderon that seems to be published  in the proceedings of ICM 1966 (as can be checked in this link: [list](https://www.mathunion.org/icm-plenary-and-invited-speakers?combine=calderon)). There is a table of contents in volume I containing the title of Calderon's paper: **Estimates for singular integral operators**.

I guessed it would be in the lost volume II. I don't know if there were any special reasons for not publishing the second volume or not.

Comment: Volume 2 was indeed Published , there are no "special reasons for not publishing". The Issue is : those Days , there was not much Digitization , hence the second volume was not in Electronic format. The available hardcopy volumes were Digitized (Scanned) & put online. We see that by the file name "xxx.ocr.pdf" where "ocr" indicates "optical character recognition" which will get the text via Scanning. That was the Case till 2006. 2010 onwards , the Original Document is itself in Electronic format , hence Scanning is not needed. Volume 2 1966 hardcopy is not yet available to get Scanned.

Comment: I found Calderon's paper under another title: ALGEBRAS OF SINGULAR INTEGRAL OPERATORS.
It was published in volume III. But still I don't understand why volume II does not exist!

Comment: @Prem Thanks for your comment.

Comment: I got a Document through https://www.pnas.org/doi/abs/10.1073/pnas.53.5.1092 , & there is a list @ https://celebratio.org/Calderon_AP/article/360/ , where the Entries 48 to 55 are related [[ Entries 52 & 55 are very close to what you want ]] hence you can try getting more there.